# How to animate body down on navbar toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Rookie here trying to learn code on my own.. I have ran into a problem where my Navbar-collapse now overlaps the content of my page and this time it is a problem because i'd like the background of the navbar-collapse to have background: transparent; .. My Jquery sucks but i'm thinking that it may need to be used here.. it also needs to account for the dropdown menus .. as they may need to push the body of the page down as well.. my code:

```
<body>

    <!-- Start Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="myNavbar">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Brand and Toggle get grouped -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target ="#navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span>Tap me!</span>
                </button>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/pencil-logo-80x80.png" class="navbar-brand" alt="Our Brand: Folio"></a>
                <a href="#" id="navLogo" class="navbar-brand">Folio</a>
            </div><!-- end navbar-header -->

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown hidden-sm">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li id="borderTop"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services Small</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- end menu -->
                    </li>

                    <!-- delete class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" to make the dropdown only open on hover -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li id="borderTop"><a href="#">Portfolio 2 Column</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio 3 Column</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio 4 Column</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Single Column</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- end menu -->
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Pages</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li id="borderTop"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Team Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page Sticky Header</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Background Video</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Preloader</a></li>

                        </ul><!-- end menu -->
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Blog</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li id="borderTop"><a href="#">Blog Overview Grid</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog Sidebar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog Post</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- end menu -->
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                </ul><!-- end navbar-right -->
            </div><!-- end navbar-responsive-collapse -->

        </div><!-- end container -->
    </nav><!-- end navbar -->

    <!-- Start Intro -->
    <div class="headerWrapper" id="intro">
        <h1>Hello. I'm Folio a <strong>small</strong> creative portfolio</h1>
        <p>Specialized in design and coding graphics and websites.</p>
    </div><!-- end Intro -->

</body>
```

CSS:

```
/*-------------------------------
      Global Styles
---------------------------------*/
body {
background: url('http://www.controltheweb.com/images/desktop-background-large/magneticField.jpg')    no-repeat center center fixed;
/*-- Makes backgrnd responsive --*/
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

#intro {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 120px;
font-family: Paytone One;
}
```

Hmm not sure if more css is needed but the navbar functions great .. it just is overlapping my page header like bootstrap usually does, but with background: transparent; it looks awful .. the only way i can think of doing this with css/html is using padding somehow but i think a slide effect would be alot nicer looking.. thnx in advance

Here is a bootply that shows my problem: http://www.bootply.com/n7dkI2ZpVX

Comment: Here's a Bootply that you can play with: http://www.bootply.com/vlsYPczs5s

Comment: thank you for showing me bootply .. i tried using jsfiddle but had issues getting my code to run .. i made a new bootply that shows my problem .. 
http://www.bootply.com/fwA2dwf391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, what you want is that the content should move down once the dropdown is opened. And should move back once nav-menu collapses. If that is right all you need to do is remove the fixed height from `#myNavbar`

```
#myNavbar {
    /* height: 80px; */
    margin-top: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: lol wow, that was easy .. thanks. i guess i've often been setting the height of my headers to style their size but since the background is transparent it didn't change my site at all and this worked perfectly.. i don't know why that made it work but thank you so much.

Comment: padding-top & bot will be my new best friends for changing navbar size now ? :)

Comment: @AlexDiVito When working with responsive designs, you need to be very careful as to what elements you give fixed heights/widths. The issue here was that the above mentioned element had a fixed height. But when the nav-bar expanded the content was more than what could fit in height, so it overflew. Now the html was rendered out of the containment area. As the height didn't increase the content area did not know that it had to go down to make space. Removing fixed height allows the div to expand when the content increases, hence letting the content are know to move further down.

Comment: @AlexDiVito Also you might find the `min-height` and `min-width` css prperties useful. They set the minimum measurements required by you and also allow to expand above that measurement when required.

Comment: @AlexDiVito Also be careful with paddings, they are not very Internet Explorer friendly.